# Migrating the Entry Model and TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'

Tags: django, python-3.x

Basically when setting up Django, I'm trying to migrate the entry model but I keep getting error with the virtual environment active of ll_env when typing `python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs`

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/The_Universe/CS/Python/Practice_PCC/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/The_Universe/CS/Python/Practice_PCC/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/The_Universe/CS/Python/Practice_PCC/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/The_Universe/CS/Python/Practice_PCC/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 112, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/The_Universe/CS/Python/Practice_PCC/learning_log/ll_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/The_Universe/CS/Python/Practice_PCC/learning_log/learning_logs/models.py", line 12, in <module>
    class Entry(models.Model):
  File "/Users/james/Desktop/The_Universe/CS/Python/Practice_PCC/learning_log/learning_logs/models.py", line 14, in Entry
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

Which should have showed like this as below from a book.

```
(ll_env)learning_log$ python manage.py makemigrations learning_logs
Migrations for 'learning_logs':
  0002_entry.py:
    - Create model Entry
(ll_env)learning_log$ python manage.py migrate
Operations to perform:
  --snip--
  Applying learning_logs.0002_entry... OK
```

So basically the error, as `TypeError` shows, is that I missed 1 required positional argument for `'on_delete'` right? So I'm trying to find `'on_delete'`part but I don't know where this is written in what script.

What exactly does the `TypeError` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are on Django 2.0 and if that is the case `on_delete` is now a required argument on `ForeignKey`. If you go ahead and add that I believe you will not see that error.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.on_delete

Comment: You mean I have to change from `topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic)` that is found from `class Entry(models.Model):` in `model.py` in `learning_logs` to `topic = models.ForeignKey.on_delete(Topic)` like this?

Comment: @James No you will do something similar to `topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` what value you use for on_delete is up to you to decide though.